# Issues with Citations on Documentation

Tags: support, documentation

What is the best practice for adding citations? For example, I proposed a topic in Excel VBA that I know already has a very comprehensive answer on SO written by Siddharth Rout (it is linked to all the time and serves as a go-to location). What is the best way to add this information to documentation? It obviously belongs in documentation, but I don't want to just copy and paste his answer saying, meekly, "credits to Siddharth Rout." It's not specifically just an issue of "stealing" reputation, but I feel as though there should be a way to actually attribute the answer to Siddharth, since it was fully and completely his content.